# boost shared_mutex destructor

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, boost, mutex

I have a multithreaded app that has to read some data often, and occasionally that data is updated. I have problems with writing by using unique_lock and problems with reading by using upgrade_lock
There is examples of my problems:

```
void unlock(){
    test.stream = 0;
    test.mtx.unlock();
}

void lock_mtx(int i){
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(test.mtx);
    test.stream = i;
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
    unlock();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

When I destruct `lock` , mutex is already unlocked by this thread, and sometimes it is locked by another thread, but destructor make it free again. After destruction of lock (in the first thread) third thread take mutex and I have two writers at the one moment

```
void lock_mtx(int i){
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(test.mtx);
    read_from_locked();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
    write_to_locked();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
}
```

The second problem, is that when some thread takes `upgrade_lock`, other threads can't read shared objects

Both of problems occur in MS VisualStudio 2013 and Windows8 x64

Answer (score 1):

```
void lock_mtx(int i)
{
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(test.mtx);
        test.stream = i;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
    }
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

The purpose of `unique_lock` and `lock_guard` is to automatically unlock the mutex when it goes out of scope. This pattern is known as RAII.

Rule of thumb: Never manually call `lock()`/`unlock()` on your (Basic|Shared)Lockable objects. It's an antipattern because

- It's extremely hard to get right (think of exception safety)
- It usually indicates a code smell (locks being held across different method calls). If you even need this, consider making the RAII lock guard (`lock_guard` or `unique_lock`) a member of the containing class, or return the `unique_lock` so the caller has the option to *explicitly* `adopt` the lock, or to just let it be automatically released by the guard.